# Url to MutlipartBody.Part in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a direct link to the file. How to download it and convert to MultipartBody.Part object to upload it with a Retrofit POST method to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need implement this code snippet

```
            InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
            File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "file_name");
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                IOUtils.copy(input, outputStream);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
            MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("YOUR_KEY" /*e.g. image*/, file.getName(), requestBody);
```

And you need to connect this dependency `implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'` for `IOUtils` class.

This approach will work with any file types (jpg, png, mp4, avi, pdf, webp, doc and so on). Happy coding.